# Detect Insert on SQL Server table and execute C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I want to create a trigger on my SQL Server table, once a new row is created, it should check if the same data (for some columns) already exists in the table; if so, it should generate a report that contains the duplicated rows.

Is this feasible please? If yes, how can I do it? Many thanks

Comment: Do you want implement unique constraint yourself?

Comment: Don't do this in a trigger. Create a unique constraint and don't allow bad data in the first place.

Comment: yes, is tis possible? (detect new row and check if the same data exist on the table, if the exist, i should generate a report )

Comment: It's not about bad data, let's say that two peoples have the same age, the same  name and live in the same country, i need to check only these data, i don't need to see the unique identifier for each person, that's why i want to get some specific data not all

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY want to do this you could do the following:

Create a SQL Agent Job that calls your C# program that generates your report.

Call that job from your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON TableName
AFTER INSERT
AS
--Do your duplicate row processing

--Call job if needed
   EXEC msdb..sp_start_job 
    @job_name = 'JobName';
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is this the best way to identify a duplicate row and generate the report or i can do it with a better solution?

Comment: Well I assume from your above comments that you want to allow them, so this should work pretty well.  Just be wary of having a large amount of single inserts as this will call that job for each one.  If you are doing batches i.e. INSERT/SELECT then this gets called for the batch.

Comment: To be more specific about your question, does the report have to be instantaneous?  If not you could schedule that job to run every XX minutes.  Or you could create a scheduled task in the Scheduler to run your program every so often. Really depends on your requirements.

Comment: Yes the report should be instantaneous, if not, scheduling it will be easier but i need it to be generated after each duplicate insert